# How to use Jquery Number Format plugin within an asp.net TextBox?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox, number-formatting

I've used this plugin with an html input and it worked with no problems,
however, when I try to implement using an asp.net textbox it doesn't work at all

Does someone know how can I implement it within a textbox from asp.net?

or maybe know if its possible to do so.

This is what I want to achieve using an asp.net textbox:

http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/examples/demo-as-you-type.html

Thank you so much, I really hope someone can enlighten me

UPDATE: code added.

asp.net control:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberFormat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

References:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../js/jquery.number.js"> </script>    
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"src="../../js/jquery.number.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#txtNumberFormat.ClientID').number( true, 2 );

});

 </script>
```

Comment: We need to see some actual code/markup; no one wants to waste time guessing what is wrong.

Comment: Coded has been added, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery is looking for a control that is literally named "txtNumberFormat.ClientID". You need

```
$('#<%= txtNumberFormat.ClientID %>').number( true, 2 );
```

so asp.net resolves the fully qualified client id inside your selector.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul!, I can't believe I forgot to add that, I won't forget next time, thank you so much both for telling me to add example code and to have given me the actual solution.